# If every open subset of R is a disjoint union of open intervals, the number of the intervals is at most countable.

Tags: real-analysis

Q:
Assume that every open subset of R is a disjoint union of open intervals.
Show that the number of the intervals is at most countable.

Could you give me some help to solve this problem?

Since R is uncountable, I thought that the number of the intervals is uncountable by intuition...

I think each subset's being open is a key point to prove this one, but I'm not sure how to do it though...

Comment: Do you know about density?

Comment: "Since R is uncountable, I thought that the number of the intervals is uncountable by intuition..." It seems you're misunderstanding. Of course there are uncountably many intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. What you shall prove is that every open set isthe union of countably many _disjoint_ intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : Every open interval contains a rational number. Hence if you have a collection of disjoint open intervals, then each of these intervals contains a distinct rational number. Use the fact that the set of rational numbers is countably infinite to conclude.

Comment: Oh! Maybe I can use the contradiction! If I suppose that there are uncountable disjoint intervals, since each interval has at least one rational number in itself(since rational number is dense in real number), there will be uncountable number of rational number. We know that the set of rational number is countable. Contradition! Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Use what you know about the rational numbers: the fact that they are countable, and the fact that the rationals are **dense in the reals**.

Clarification: Yes, there *are* uncountably many intervals in $\mathbb R$.

However, you are being asked to prove that every open set in $\mathbb R$ is the union of countably many **disjoint** intervals.